# Adding user data to manage page in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been following the Add Profile Data to User Class part of this tutorial to add more fields to my registration page in MVC 5. So far it's working fine and I have no issues. The problem is now I'm not sure on how that gets displayed on the Manage page where the user can see his profile info like changing his password. For example, I want to add on a first and last name on that page.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#ap

Here is a screenshot of the page I'm talking about:
http://puu.sh/dcMmj/82ddd8fc97.PNG

My project is what Visual Studio creates for you with the added first and last name in the registration page. Added this in the following Identity Model like in the tutorial

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I need to add something here in the ManageController.cs but I'm not sure.

```
// GET: /Manage/Index
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
            : "";

        var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            HasPassword = HasPassword(),
            PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()),

           // I think it goes in here somewhere


        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your **var model** with this code:

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

var model = new IndexViewModel {
    HasPassword = HasPassword(),
    PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
    TwoFactor = user.TwoFactorEnabled,
    Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(user),
    BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(user),
    FirstName = user.FirstName        
}
```

Now you can use model.FirstName in your View.

Comment: My project is what Visual Studio creates for you with the added first and last name in the registration page. Added the extra stuff in the Identity Model from what the tutorial showed me.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for taking the time to help me. It's working now, but it was giving me an error in till I added in the await to the line. I'll post the change here in case someone has a similar problem.

`ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());`

Comment: I try to get this working. But i get the error Models.indexViewModel does not contain a definition for 'name'.

Comment: Check your indexViewModel class, it seems to me that you forgot to implement the 'name' property or it is set to non-public.